# Stripity Stripe Module Not Found

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I know I must be missing something very minor, but I'm unable to figure it out. I've search the documentation and looked for other examples but have been unable to find one.

I'm just trying to create a session using the [Stripity_stripe](https://github.com/code-corps/stripity_stripe) library. I've included it in my dependencies and updated my config.

In my controller I have the import function at the top like so

```
import Stripe
```

And then attempting to create a session calling it via

```
Stripe.Session.create()
```

However, I'm still receiving the error

```
(UndefinedFunctionError) function Stripe.Session.create/1 is undefined (module Stripe.Session is not available)
```

What is the correct way to import this library and call the corresponding function?

Comment: Which version of `stripity_stripe` did you add to your `mix.exs`?

Comment: "~> 2.0.0", just took it from the install guide on their Github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sidenote:* `"~> 2.0.0"` is the wrong way to refer dependencies supporting semantic versioning. One should use `"~> 2.0"`. That way you’ll get `"2.7"` which is the latest one.

That said, you’re using version `2.0.1` which doesn't have the Session module. Use [{:stripity_stripe, "~> 2.7"}](https://hex.pm/packages/stripity_stripe) in your `mix.exs` file.

Comment: I have submitted a pull request to amend installation instructions FWIW. https://github.com/code-corps/stripity_stripe/pull/588